# write FileOutputStream (received as String) to file

Tags: java, string, jsp, pdf, fileoutputstream

I am receiving the FileOutputStream as String in my servlet, How can I write it to file.

I tried to convert the string to bytes and than assigned it to new FileOutputStream, it generates the file but says the format is corrupted.

I tried various codes but none of them is working.

```
File file = new File("d:/file1.pdf");
        String content = request.getParameter("TextB1");

        try (FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream(file)) {

            // get the content in bytes
            byte[] contentInBytes = content.getBytes();

            fop.write(contentInBytes);
            fop.flush();
            fop.close();

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: What's passed into `TextB1`? Is it actually a PDF file?

Comment: actually I am getting FileOutputStream from third party applet in javascript while doing some document varification using that applet,then I save it to hidden field and submit the form. Now in my servlet I am getting that as a string. and I need to save that as file (in pdf format).

Comment: my question is not about how to create pdf file, I am getting the fileoutputstream in string and I need to write it to file.

Comment: To a PDF file... right?

Comment: the fileoutputstream itself is a pdf file, I am able to write it also but the file gets corrupted.

Comment: It's not "corrupted", it's just not PDF format. You're saving it as plain text. Open it in a text editor and it should display fine.

Comment: it shows the string of fileoutputstream if I open it in text editor

Comment: Ok... so what's the problem?

Comment: it shows like JVBERi0xLjQNCjUgMCBvYmoNCjw8DQovVHlwZSAvWE9iamVjdA0KL1N1YnR5cGUgL0ltYWdlDQovRmlsdGVyIC9GbGF0ZURlY29kZQ0KL0xlbmd0aCAzMDc5OQ0KL1dpZHRoIDIwMw0KL0hlaWdodCAyMDYNCi9CaXRzUGVyQ29tcG9uZW50IDgN....... actually its not a text content...

Comment: That's base64 encoded. And it looks like it may indeed be a PDF file. Try `byte[] contentInBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(content);`. I've reopened the question.

Comment: let me elaborate for better understanding, I am using third party applet for docuement verification, which takes pdf as input and returns the FileOutputStream of verified document (which is in pdf format), since this is returned in applet, but I need to store that as a file on my server. Hence I am saving that bytes in one hidden field and pass that to another jsp page where I need to store that to a file.

Comment: thanks a lot, I'll try as suggested.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, indeed it worked like a charm :) Many thanks

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Probably the issue is due the fact that you should need to decode the content if is a PDF file.

something like this should probably work:

```
BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
byte[] decodedBytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(content.getBytes());
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `sun.misc`. They're internal APIs that may be removed at any time (I think they're expected to in Java 9).